# AngularJS 2 - Calling a RESTful Service - Fat Arrow

Tags: angularjs, rest

Was hoping someone could help me.  I'm completely brand new to AngularJS2, so forgive me if I don't provide everything that is needed.

Quite simply I am making a call out to a RESTful service to get some data.  The RESTful call is fine and the correct data is returned to the component.  When I then try to grab that information and store it in a class level variable, the variable always stays as "undefined".  I just can seem to grab the RESTful data out of the component call.

Can anyone help?  What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure I'm messing up on the fat arrow somewhere.  Remember, this is AngularJS2 not ver 1.

Thank you.

**COMPONENT:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { LocationDetails } from './models/locationdetails';
import { LocationService } from './services/location.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1>',
    providers: [LocationService],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public locationDetails: LocationDetails[];

    constructor(private _locationService: LocationService) {
        this._locationService = _locationService;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getLocations();

    }

    private getLocations = (): void => {
        this._locationService.getLocationsService()
            .subscribe((response: LocationDetails[]) => { this.locationDetails = response; },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log(this.locationDetails));  //<-- this.locationDetails value has the return data from the RESTful

        **console.log('HELLO ' + this.locationDetails); //<-- this.locationDetails is now undefined. Was fine just one line up.**
    }

}
```

**SERVICE**

```
    import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Configuration } from '../shared/app.configuration';
import { LocationDetails } from '../models/locationdetails';

@Injectable()
export class LocationService {
    private _url: string

    constructor(private _http: Http, private _configuration: Configuration) {
        this._http = _http;
        this._url = _configuration.baseUrl;
    }   

    public getLocationsService = (): Observable<LocationDetails[]> => {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((response: Response) => <LocationDetails[]>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        debugger;
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
export class LocationDetails {
    Active: boolean;
    AutoTransfer: boolean;
    CompanyNumber: number;
    CurrencyID: number;
    EntityID: number;
    IndividualTaxesEnabled: boolean;
    IsPrimaryState: boolean;
    LocationCode: string;
    LocationID: number;
    LocationName: string;
    MTP_Address: string;
    MeasurementOptionID: number;
    PriceRateID: number;
    RegionID: number;
    RemitAddressTypeID: number;
    RemitToAddressEnabled: boolean;
    SMTP_Address: string;
    SMTP_Port: string;
    StateProvince: string;
    bCustomPurchaseOrderRemitEnabled: boolean;
    txtInvoiceFooter: string;
    vcDefaultTaxLabel: string;

}
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question

Comment: I thought I did?  I did attach screenshots, but they seemed to have turned up as hyperlinks labeled "Component" and "Service" on my post.  Have to work out how to show them as pictures on the screen.  But clicking on the links does bring up the code.

Comment: If you edit your post and paste the code into the question, formatting it with the `{}` button on the toolbar, you will get a better response than linking to external sites

Comment: Thanks.  Just did that.  Didn't format too well, but I got it up there.

Comment: Functions *inside* the `.subscribe` method execute **after** subsequent functions *outside* the `.subscribe` method. The `.subscribe` method stores those functions and executes them at a later time. The value *outside* the `.subscribe` method is undefined because the function *inside* the `.subscribe` method hasn't executed yet.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Question? What if I make say 3 service calls to get data which I then want to massage. I will always then have nulls as the subscribe will never execute until the end. How can I get around this? Place waits until every subscribe has executed?  Not all data will be shown on the front end.  We have code that performs calculations and need to pull data out from the database (via RESTful) as it goes along.